# How to use with css selectors in xslt file?

Tags: html, css, xslt

I am new with xslt programming.

I need to perform some special styling, to get the below output:

-- TEXT1.......................................................TEXT2

Actually there are two issues here:

1. Line of dots between items
2. Custom bullet symbol for li elements in ul

As I found ([1-Line of dots css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776592/line-of-dots-between-items)  ,  [2-custom bullet css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and)) to do that I need to use with "before" selector

Here the suggested code (from above second link):

```
li:before {
  content: "-";
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Until now, I wrote the special css style in the xslt as code below:

```
  <xsl:template match="listItem">
    <ul style="list-style-type:disc; list-style-position: inside; padding-left: 0;">
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="para"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

Now, I need to insert the "before" selector to implement my issue.
I'd love to know what the syntax of this is,
Or alternatively, I would be happy to know other ways.

Thanks!

**Updated:**
I added some code to the question.

Comment: Before what ? and where ? What is your current output ? and what is expected ?

Comment: by the above links, I want to write this in style attribute: li:before {
  content: "+";
  padding-right: 5px;
}

Comment: @Vebbie, I updated my question. and write another comment

Comment: You can put your styles in a `<style>` tag. See https://html.com/tags/style/